# SearchBox for every column Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a kendo grid on a page

[image]

I'm using that Searchbox from the toolbar of the grid.
It is resolved this way:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GGISServices.Models.Model>()
    .Name("grid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "newGrid" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {....}
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
    toolbar.Template(@<text>
        <div class="toolbar">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id='FieldFilter' placeholder="Cauta...">
                    </div>
                </div>                    
             </div>
        </div>
    </text>);
    })
```

and in javascript I have added this code:

```
  $("#FieldFilter").keyup(function () {
        var val = $('#FieldFilter').val();
        console.log(val);
        if (val) {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
                logic: "or",
                filters: [
                    {
                        field: "Field1",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: val
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Field2",
                        operator: "contains",
                        value: val
                    }
                ]
            });
        } else {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({});
    }

    });
```

It is working ok, but now the client wants a different searching, a serachbox for every column, like in this DevExpress grid. 
[image]

Can I achieve that using the Kendo grid?

Comment: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row this is probably what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called 'Grid / Filter row' and it is available for Kendo ASP.NET MVC. It comes as out of the box feature.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GGISServices.Models.Model>()
.Name("grid")

...

.Filterable(f=> f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
```

[Demo and Complete sample code](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-row)